# Unicode Parsing Error with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

uClient = uReq('http://www.google.com')
page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'), 'lxml')
print(page_soup.find_all('p'))
```

...produces the following error:

```
C:\>python ws1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ws1.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(page_soup.find_all('p'))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xa9' in position 40
: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have searched, in vain, for a solution as every post I have read suggests using a specific encoding none of which has eradicated the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that `page_soup.find()` is returning a character that can't be printed in your console.

Comment: Do you know of an encoding that will facilitate this or can I request (pun intended) that the offending character be ignored?

Comment: I've just made an edit to my answer, I originally included a function that wasn't necessary at all. The new answer is a little more complete as well.

Comment: Have you set the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable on your windows machine to utf-8? And declared # coding: utf-8 on the first line of your script? If you're allowed you could also pull the data with requests. In py3 the response.content returns bytes, so you can declare that there as well (utf_response = response.content.decode('utf-8'). These things solve my issues every time. .

Comment: @jlaur that's called a shot in the dark.  `#coding: utf8` declares the source encoding and has nothing to do with the libraries used.  `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` usually works on Linux, and might work on windows with `chcp 65001` in a console or when redirecting to a file, but otherwise would cause garbage to be printed.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen - I missed the part about running the thing from console. So your right. In chcp 850 a python file with print("æ, ø, å") prints gibberish if you don't do a chcp 65001 (and have a font that supports those characters like Lucida Console instead of the default Raster-font). So I was talking about the situation where the script is run from Python, writing to files and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to print a Unicode string that contains characters that can't be represented in the encoding used by your console.

It appears you're using the Windows command line, which means your problem could be solved simply by switching to Python 3.6 - it bypasses the console encoding altogether and sends Unicode straight to Windows.

If that's not possible, you can encode the string yourself and specify that unprintable characters should be replaced with an escape sequence. Then you must decode it again so that `print` will work properly.

```
bstr = page_soup.find_all('p').encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='backslashreplace')
print(bstr.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```